# ANY clause on a subquery using jpa criteria API

Tags: java, jpql

I have two entities Document and Property where a document has a set of properties:

```
@Entity 
public class Document{
 @Id
 private Integer id;

 @OneToMany
 private Set<Property> properties;
}
```

And

```
@Entity
public class Property{
 @Id
 private Integer    id;

 private String key;
 private String value;
}
```

I want to implement the following JPQL query using Criteria API:

```
SELECT d FROM Document d 
    WHERE "value11" = ANY(SELECT p.value FROM d.properties p WHERE p.key="key11")
```

I tried the following:

```
EntityManager em = PersistenceManager.INSTANCE.getEntityManager();

CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Document> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Document.class);

Root<Document> fromDoc = query.from(Document.class);

Subquery<String> subQuery = query.subquery(String.class);

Root<Property> subRoot = subQuery.from(Property.class);

subQuery.select(subRoot.get(Property_.value));

SetJoin<Document, Property> join = fromDoc.join(Document_.properties, JoinType.INNER);

subQuery.select(join.<String> get("value"));
subQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(join.<String> get("key"), "key11"));

query.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(criteriaBuilder.any(subQuery), "value11"));

Query q = em.createQuery(query);
List<Document> docs = q.getResultList();

PersistenceManager.INSTANCE.close();
```

But I got this exception:

> Exception Description: The query has not been defined correctly, the
>   expression builder is missing.  For sub and parallel queries ensure
>   the queries builder is always on the left. Query:
>   ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Document )    at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.invalidBuilderInQuery(QueryException.java:689)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.SQLSelectStatement.appendFromClauseToWriter(SQLSelectStatement.java:537)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.SQLSelectStatement.printSQL(SQLSelectStatement.java:1704)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Pleas check if your persistence provider implements methods for `ANY`, `ALL`and `SOME`. If not you could anyway re-formulate the query using `"value11"  IN (subquery)`

Comment: Thank you Marmite Bomber. I'm using eclipseLink 2.6.1 and yes there is an any method on CriteriaBuilder class:
https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.6/index.html